# Invisible Character For NSString

Tags: ios, nsstring

Hi can any one please tell me how to add invisible character in my nsstring specially this character ¿. I need this for making a csv file the file will be liked [this](http://screencast.com/t/VNOmaEddNKda).  For example \n add a new line character.

Comment: ¿ is quite visible to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `unicode` characters for that.

Here is a [table](http://unicode-table.com/en/#0033) of unicode characters corresponding their string values.

[Here](http://www.unicode.org/charts/) is chart of character code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ASCII value of that character and add into NSString like:

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",168];
NSLog(@"%@",str);
```